# While cloning a VSTS repo on local, facing SSL certificate issue

Tags: git, visual-studio, ssl, azure-devops, clone

While cloning a repo from VSTS i am facing the below error in Visual Studio. "SSL certificate problem"
How can i ignore SSL certificate or add that certificate in Visual Studio.

[image: Error]

Comment: What's the result after trying my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to ignore certificate validation is calling ***git config --global http.sslVerify false*** command.

To trust a certificate, you can try these steps and check the result:

1. Export the certificate through browser (e.g. chrome): Click lock icon in address bar > Certificate > Certification Path > Select top-most certificate in the chain > View Certificate > Copy to file (Choose Base-64 encoded X.509).
2. Copy content to ca-bundle.crt file (check **http.sslcainfo** value by calling ***git config –l*** command)

More information: [Adding a corporate (or self-signed) certificate authority to git.exe’s store](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store/)

Comment: i have ignored the certificate with the above command in local git bash config but still the same error coming up.

Comment: Its working now after i restarted visual studio & yes its showing the http.sslverify=false in config. Will update if any issue at later stage.

Comment: Thanks @starian-chen-msft. 
Exporting the cetificate (step 1 above) and adding it to the end of C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt (step 2 above) worked for me.